# Динамическая компиляция на c++

Tags: c#, c++, компиляция

Динамическая компиляция на c# осуществляется работой классов :

> using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

и

> using Microsoft.CSharp;

А есть ли аналогичные классы в с++? Если да - насколько похож процесс компиляции? Можно откомпилировать программу написанную на c# средствами С++ компилятора ?

Comment: @Abyx, это если есть `c++` в системе :-D

Comment: Теоретически можно и так и так, через вызов exec, ну c# ещё можно собрать используя cli-библиотеку.

Comment: _Можно откомпилировать программу написанную на c# средствами С++ компилятора ?_ - С++ компилятор здесь - это компилятор написанный на С++, или компилятор понимающий только код С++?

Comment: @Grundy под этим я имел в виду класс аналог `CodeDom.Compiler`

Comment: Нет, нету. Посему, нет, совершенно не похож, т. к. отсутствует. Средствами компилятора C++ можно "откомпилировать" программу на C# только если использовать компилятор C#, написанный на С++. А возможность вызова компиляторов во время выполнения не касается уже ни языков, ни их компиляторов.

Comment: @Abyx `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(...`

Comment: @alexolut, это если из C# вызывать

Comment: @Grundy а... ну тогда надо и вовсе видимо `system("csc.exe src.cs");`

Comment: Компилятор - дело неблагодарное и сложное. Та же, например, библиотеки "оболочки" borland поддерживают компиляцию. Вопрос зачем? Есть более "простой" метод компиляции - инжекция и git. Если у вас простое "алгебраическое" выражение - вы на него можете "сгенерировать" git, - это пожалуй максимум что можно сделать ручками.